# Merge rows, sum one column of values, and keep earliest start time and latest end time

Tags: excel, vba

I have been able to find code that will merge rows and delete the duplicate rows that are not needed any more and sum one of the columns. However, those codes are based on ActiveCells, which will not work for me. I need this to work on a large range of data. As in the example below, there will be rows of 2, 3, or more rows that need to be merged. But I also have an additional requirement that I just cannot find a solution for. Below is a small set of data that we can use as an example. There are 4 columns here (there are 5 more columns in the actual data set, but they are all duplicate data and not needed for this example) that represents the challenge. I would need to merge these three rows into one, add the values in column B (continued below)

[image: Before]

The final result would be this where the earliest Start date & time is kept and the latest start date & time are also kept:

[image: After]

The data will be in columns A through Z (row 1 is a header column), and data is added hourly. For all my other code, I typically limit the number of rows to 2000. We have not exceeded that yet. I have a custom menu that I will use to trigger the code as the purpose is to have as little user input as possible (automation is key). Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Comment: Will the date and times always be in order like this? If not, you will need some if statements to find the min and max times to put in those cells, you can easily add up the minutes for any cell that is the same. You will need to loop through all the cells and find copies, and add them together. It also depends on where your information is. Will it be sorted first?

Comment: @histerical Yes, the data is always sorted and the start and end dates are part of the sort order. The example only shows the highlighted area as sorted. I just threw it together for reference. I will edit my question to show the entire range where the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `A` is sorted then try this code:

```
Sub Test()

  Dim Rng As Range, dRng As Range
  Dim i As Long, LR As Long 'lastrow

    With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False
     .EnableEvents = False
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A2:D2")

    For i = 3 To LR
     If Rng(1) = Cells(i, 1) Then          
      Set Rng = Range(Rng(1), Cells(i, 4))
     Else
      If Rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoSub mSub
      Set Rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))
     End If
    Next

    If Rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoSub mSub
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then dRng.EntireRow.Delete

    With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True
     .EnableEvents = True
     .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

  Exit Sub

mSub:

    With WorksheetFunction
     Rng(2) = .Sum(Rng.Columns(2))
     Rng(3) = .Min(Rng.Columns(3))
     Rng(4) = .Max(Rng.Columns(4))
    End With

    If dRng Is Nothing Then
     Set dRng = Range(Rng(2, 1), Rng(Rng.Count))
    Else
     Set dRng = Union(dRng, Range(Rng(2, 1), Rng(Rng.Count)))
    End If

  Return
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. And, of course, as soon as I implemented this, the requirements changed. Should I update the question with the new requirements, or create a new question (with a reference to this one) and post the new information? This will also need to show an expanded version of the example from this question.

Comment: @IronMan, You are welcome,if new requirements are simple maybe I can edit this answer, but I think new question is better if this code need a lot of   change.

Comment: I will create a new question titled "Merge rows, sum one column of values, and keep earliest start time and latest end time - Part 2" because there is added criteria for determining which rows to perform the subs on.

Comment: Here is the new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561890/merge-rows-sum-one-column-of-values-and-keep-earliest-start-time-and-latest-en)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick bit of code I put together for you. It will do what you are asking for, but I believe there are better ways of doing it with more information on what you are looking for.

```
Sub combineLikes()

endRng = Range("D92000").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2
Do Until i > endRng
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value + Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value
        If Range("C" & i).Value > Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value Then Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value
        If Range("D" & i).Value < Range("D" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value Then Range("D" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        endRng = endRng - 1
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```