# Merge rows, sum one column of values, and keep earliest start time and latest end time - Part 2

Tags: excel, vba

This question adds additional requirements to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515251/merge-rows-sum-one-column-of-values-and-keep-earliest-start-time-and-latest-en).

This first screen shot shows all the columns and a sample of rows that we are working with. The data will be sorted. The sub will need to match all the data that is shown in Red text:

[image]

The code will need to identify these and then merge the two rows, keeping the earliest Start date & time and the latest End date & time, and add the data in the last two columns respectively. In the below example the data values are 0 in the last column. If there was a 5 in the top one and 243 in the second line (of the yellow highlighted area), then column I would show 158 and column J would show 248 for the final values.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test2()

  Dim Rng As Range, dRng As Range
  Dim i As Long, LR As Long 'lastrow

    With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False
     .EnableEvents = False
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A2:J2")

    For i = 3 To LR
     If Rng(1) = Cells(i, 1) And Rng(2) = Cells(i, 2) And Rng(3) = Cells(i, 3) _
        And Rng(4) = Cells(i, 4) And Rng(5) = Cells(i, 5) And Rng(6) = Cells(i, 6) Then

      Set Rng = Range(Rng(1), Cells(i, 10))

     Else
      If Rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoSub mSub
      Set Rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10))
     End If
    Next

    If Rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then GoSub mSub
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then dRng.EntireRow.Delete

    With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True
     .EnableEvents = True
     .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

  Exit Sub

mSub:

    With WorksheetFunction
     Rng(7) = .Min(Rng.Columns(7))
     Rng(8) = .Max(Rng.Columns(8))
     Rng(9) = .Sum(Rng.Columns(9))
     Rng(10) = .Sum(Rng.Columns(10))
    End With

    If dRng Is Nothing Then
     Set dRng = Range(Rng(2, 1), Rng(Rng.Count))
    Else
     Set dRng = Union(dRng, Range(Rng(2, 1), Rng(Rng.Count)))
    End If

  Return
End Sub
```

Comment: While you were working on this, I was also trying to get this to work. I had an issue that your answer fixed for me. This does exactly what I need. Thanks for all your help. Unless there is a new request, or proposed change, I think I am finally done with this project!

Comment: @IronMan,You are Welcome.